# Duda con bitly y c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, consola

estoy intentando acortar urls con bitly mediante la consola de c#, el problema es que me sale el error:

```
Error: System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at BitlyTest.Program.Shorten(String groupId, String token, String url) in Program.cs:line 54
```

Este es el código:

```
class Program{
        static void Main(string[] args){
            Console.WriteLine("Enter group Id:");
            string groupId = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter token:");
            string token = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter URL:");
            string url = Console.ReadLine();
            Shorten(groupId, token, url);
        }

        public static void Shorten(string groupId, string token, string url){
            string post = "{\"group_guid\": \"" + groupId + "\", \"long_url\": \"" + url + "\"}";
            string shortUrl = url;
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://api-ssl.bitly.com/v4/shorten");
            try{
                System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate (object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors) { return true; };
                request.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = false;
                request.Method = "POST";
                request.ContentLength = post.Length;
                request.ContentType = "application/json";
                request.Headers.Add("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
                request.Host = "api-ssl.bitly.com";
                request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
                using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream()){
                    byte[] postBuffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(post);
                    requestStream.Write(postBuffer, 0, postBuffer.Length);
                }using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse()) //línea con el error
                {
                    using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream()){
                        using (StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(responseStream)){
                            string json = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
                            shortUrl = Regex.Match(json, @"""link"": ?""(?<link>[^,;]+)""").Groups["link"].Value;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }catch (Exception ex){
                Console.WriteLine("Error: " + ex);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("\nShortened URL: " + shortUrl);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
```

¿Alguno podría ayudarme? dejé comentada la línea en la que sale el error por si acaso
He intentado solucionar el error leyendo pero no he dado con la solución. La idea es luego poder implementar esta idea en C# con MVC en un WebService. 
Espero que puedan ayudarme, gracias.

Comment: No veo que coloques un token de acceso

Comment: Ah, olvídalo ya vi que lo insertas.

Comment: Devuelve forbiden.. tal vez el token esta mal?

Comment: Copié y pegué el token de bitly pero me sale el 403 Forbiden

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo primero que debes conseguir es el `Token de acceso genérico` o general.

Para realizar esto ve a tu cuenta Bitly, click en el menú de arriba a la derecha > `Settings > Advanced Settings > API Support > click en el enlace que dice Generic Access Tokens`.

Otra via es click en el menú de arriba a la derecha > `My Profile > Generic Access Tokens`

Ingresa tu contraseña y debes generar un Token Genérico. Esto es lo que usarás para conectarte desde tu aplicación.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Te dejo un sitio para que leas más sobre este tipo de aplicaciones aquí la [documentación](https://dev.bitly.com/v4_documentation.html) y encuentra la sección para `aplicaciones de acceso simple` o `single account application`.

El tema de la autenticación ha cambiado un poco puedes verificarlo aquí:
[Documentación para Aplicaciones de Acceso Simple](https://dev.bitly.com/v4/#section/Application-using-a-single-account.)

Cómo te autenticas con la API de Bitly ha cambiado con la V4. Anteriormente el Token de autenticación se obtenía al realizar una solicitud y se lo conocía como `access_token`. La V4 ahora requiere que el token de autenticación sea enviado como parte del Encabezado de Autorización en cada solicitud. `(Authorization header)`.

Si no lo consigues utiliza una aplicación de tipo Postman para verificar que estés realizando correctamente las solicitudes y el llenado del Authorization Header.

Espero te haya ayudado.

Comment: Hice exactamente los mismo pasos que mencionaste pero aún no ha funcionado. 
Al token lo generé como muestras y la versión es la v4. 
Desconozco el uso de postman pero gracias, sirve como dato. Veré de leer la documentación que has dejado